# How to copy the data in last row and copy to the last row of a table in the same worksheet automatically using excel vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find way to `select` and `copy` the data from the last row (*column F to I*) to the last row of the `'summary'` table (*column O to R*).

For now this is the code that I found, but it seems that it can paste within the same range of column with different row.

For example, it will copy data `F38:I38` and paste the data at `F40:I40`. However, what I want is to copy data from `F38:I38` and the code will find the last row of the `'summary'` table and paste the data `F38:I38` to the last empty row.

Is it possible to target the last two rows of the same worksheet, but different number of cell? Is there any way I can automate this process?

```
Dim lastRowI As Integer 

lastRowI = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
ws.Activate
ws.Range(Cells(lastRowI, 6), Cells(lastRowI, 9)).Select
Selection.Copy
ws.Range(Cells(lastRowI + 2, 6), Cells(lastRowI + 2, 9)).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last row of the summary table range is:

```
Dim rngLastRow As Range
Set rngLastRow = Range("N4").CurrentRegion
Set rngLastRow = rngLastRow.Rows(rngLastRow.Rows.Count)
```

Comment: I'm sorry but where should i put this code, sorry as i do not know much on VBA

Comment: Wherever you need the last row in a range.

Comment: when i need to paste something on the last row, do i have to +1 or add 1so that the data will not overwrite the data on the last row?

Comment: If you paste on the last row, you will overwrite whatever is there. If you want to paste one row below the last row, then that would be rngLastRow.Offset(1,0)

Comment: thanks for the knowledge on how to gets the last row. it helps alot !!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming  that you have named your table "Summary",

```
   //Select "Summary" table
   ActiveSheet.Range("Summary").Select
   //Go to the last row of "Summary" table
   Selection.End(xlDown).Select
   //Go to Next row 
   Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
```

Comment: I tried this but it will replace the last data on the Summary table. How do i make it so that it paste on the next row?

Comment: One way is     Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select 

I modified the code in the original answer for clarity